# Number of badges out of sync

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

I have 4 G + 36 S + 98 B badges. Should be a total of **138**

The total number of badges was correct until about 3 days ago. Now it shows a total of **50** bagdes.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/86611/shiraz-bhaiji

Maybe this is due to a recalc, but it has had the same wrong answer for several days now.

Comment: Where you see 50 badges?

Comment: Above the badges section

Comment: So please add this to the question and also adding a screenshot is always a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number you are seeing is the **total number of unique badges**.

As you can see, for multiple badges of the same type, a number is displayed next to the badge.

[image]

Taking into consideration multiple badges of the same type, your grand total (at time of writing) is 138.

Comment: +1. Easy to do the math on the page, too, and confirm that the total is 138.